# Creating base loading view with prism

Tags: c#, mvvm, asynchronous, prism

My prism application has a lot of async operations called from my view models.
In some cases, I want the view to be disabled and display some kind of busy indicator until the viewmodel gets back the result from the async operation.

I though of creating a base view which will implement this behavior (i.e have a dependency property of IsLoading which will disable the view and display a busy indicator above it).
The problem is, I'm not sure how to implement this base view.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I wrote a LoadingView which does the job, I think.

`public class LoadingView : UserControl
    {
        private object content;`

```
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(IsLoadingProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsLoadingProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private ProgressRing m_RingControl;

    public LoadingView()
    {
        m_RingControl = new ProgressRing();
        m_RingControl.IsActive = false;
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsLoading.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsLoadingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsLoading", typeof(bool), typeof(LoadingView), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsActivePropertyChanged));

    private static void IsActivePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadingView view = d as LoadingView;
        if (view != null)
        {
            // Loading - show ring control
            if (((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
            {
                view.content = view.Content;
                view.Content = view.m_RingControl;
                view.m_RingControl.IsActive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                view.m_RingControl.IsActive = false;
                view.Content = view.content;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and i put binding on LoadingView.IsLoading with some IsLoading (or IsBusy) in the viewmodel

Answer (score 2):

This is a subject that can get really complex really fast.

I would advise a small change in approach - instead of putting an IsBusy property in a base viewmodel, instead make it abstract so that each derived viewmodel has to implement its own specific check.

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public abstract bool IsBusy { get; }

}

public class FancyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public override bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return [check #1] && [check #2]...; }
    }
}
```

Now it is up to each specific viewmodel to determine whether it is busy. A crude mechanism is to have a counter which you increment every time an async function is kicked off, and decrement it when the operation ends - if its value is equal to zero then there are no current async operations. When using flags or counters be aware of various property reading issues that can occur because of [compiler optimisations](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/), learn to use the volatile keyword in the right place.

Alternatively instead of keeping a counter you could use the thread safe [CountdownEvent class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If you want to get really advanced then you can check out the various thread signalling mechanisms in the [System.Threading namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), or look at [task parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx) and the [Task object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my intention was more about the view than the viewmodel.

Comment: @user2853648 I'm aware of that, my answer was aimed at assisting you with marshalling the results of a bunch of async methods into one `IsBusy` property. If you are still looking for a control, try the [BusyIndicator](http://elegantcode.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/)